# Identification of a bug in Vasai, India

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can someone please let me know what insect this is?

This may be something very common, but this is the first time I have seen them and that too suddenly in a large number.

They were mostly on plants, but the only clear image I got was of the one sitting on this bike. Image captured in Vasai, India

[image]

[image]

(Brought into Biology SE from https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHcrg.jpg)

Comment: It looks like Oides andrewesi.